# How to use getItem in DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to get item list created by a user from following dynamodb table.
[image]

For this, I set the parameter like this.

```
...
cons userId = '***'
const params = {
 TableName: MyTable,
 Key: {
  'userId': { S: userId }
 }
}
...
```

But I'm facing following error.

```
Unable to read item. Error JSON: {
  "message": "The provided key element does not match the schema",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2020-10-14T13:30:23.292Z",
  "requestId": "RCOGBKA34G61KDTIO9U4C16OBRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 36.415675258395865
}
```

What's my wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You've specified a key of `userId`, but your screenshot shows a partition key named `pk`.

The error message is saying the key you provided (`userId`) does not match the schema (`PK`).

I noticed that `userId` is an attribute on your item and *not* in the primary key.  In this case, you can use the `scan` operation.  The arguments to the `scan` operation would look something like this:

```
{
  "TableName": "<YOUR TABLE NAME>",
  "FilterExpression": "#userId = :userId",
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":userId": {
      "S": "<USER ID HERE>"
    }
  },
  "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
    "#userId": "userId"
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that the `scan` operation will read every record in your table.  Also, scan may return paginated results, so make sure to [read up on how pagination works](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Pagination) in DynamoDb.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, So do you mean that the query couldn't be done without pk and sk in Key in Params?

Comment: That is correct.  The query operation works by specifying the primary key values.  You can specify the partition key by itself (PK in your case), or the partition key *and* the sort key.   More info in the API docs; https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html

Comment: If you are trying to search your database using a non-key attribute (`userId` is not in your primary key), you'll need to use the `scan` operation.

Comment: I tried with scan and it works without error, but it returns empty result.

Comment: Although it wasn't your original question, I've updated my answer to show you what a scan operation for `userId` would look like.